# Pourquoi bumper des questions qui ne seront jamais acceptées ?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Récemment, l'utilisateur Jardin de Frosted Flakes a malheureusement supprimé son compte. Depuis, je vois régulièrement des questions qui n'avaient pas de réponse acceptée et qui sont bumpées en Top Questions ("*bumped to the homepage by Community♦*").

Cette [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33758/l-engagement-vers-la-mise-en-%c5%93uvre) par exemple. J'en ai vu au moins 5 ou 6 ces dernières semaines, quelle est la démarche derrière ? Pourquoi remonter une question qui ne pourra jamais être acceptée, et pourquoi attendre que l'utilisateur ait supprimé son compte pour en remonter plein ?

Answer (score 4):

> This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has
>   marked it active so that they can be reviewed.

Ma traduction : *Cette question a reçu des réponses qui peuvent être bonnes ou mauvaises ; le système la ramène en tête de liste **pour fins de révision.*** Ce n'est pas pour fins d'acceptation. Lire l'aide s'avère utile pour comprendre la valeur de l'acceptation des réponses :

> Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept
>   the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that
>   answers your question well. ([What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers))
>
> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final
>   statement indicating that the question has now been answered
>   perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that
>   worked for them personally. Not every user comes back to accept an
>   answer, and of those who do, they might not change the accepted answer
>   even if a newer, better answer comes along later. ([What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer))

Il est mieux d'attendre d'avoir une bonne réponse plutôt que d'accepter des réponses en quelques minutes sans que la communauté ne se soit penchée sur leur valeur, ce qui pourrait même décourager certains autres utilisateurs de contribuer s'ils considéraient le sujet clos plutôt que mal clos, mais ultimement **l'acceptation n'est pas obligatoire et signifie seulement que la réponse est au goût de la personne qui pose la question**. Une telle sélection ne fait aucunement autorité. Un minimum d'humilité est de mise.

En fait même le vote relatif ne fait aucunement autorité, il fait plutôt état d'une préférence, parce qu'aucune expertise n'est garantie, puisque le site n'exige pas l'identification des utilisateurs ni une formation dans le domaine par exemple, parce que l'affluence sérieuse de francophones est possiblement faible et l'emploi de sources crédibles, variable, et parce que l'appui aux réponses est possiblement dicté par leur langue de rédaction et la compréhension du fait français qui n'est pas à première vue le fait de la majorité des utilisateurs du réseau, pas plus que la langue n'est généralement leur domaine par ailleurs. La production participative n'est pas un gage de vérité.

De surcroît, si le goût de la personne n'a rien à voir avec la valeur de la réponse acceptée, **plusieurs utilisateurs n'auront encore même pas la connaissance ou la compétence requise pour déterminer si la réponse est bonne objectivement** et ce ne sont même pas tous les utilisateurs qui reviendraient changer leur sélection si une meilleure réponse se présentait.

Il est donc parfaitement de bon aloi de voir des contenus variés remonter en tête de liste, a fortiori si peu de gens les préfèrent, **pour qu'on puisse les vérifier et y ajouter** (ce qui fut fait avec certaines des questions de l'utilisateur dont tu parles ; c'est là le sens du message initial de l'utilisateur [*Community*](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)) indépendamment de la breloque de l'association à un utilisateur particulier ou de sa capacité d'accepter une « bonne réponse », qui comme tu l'as lu est loin d'être une panacée de toutes façons. Sans compter que **certaines questions n'appellent même pas de réponse définitive** qui soit objectivement « la bonne ». C'est le cas par exemple de [questions subjectives](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) jugées constructives ou de questions dont l'accès au savoir requis pour répondre est entravé, en cours d'élaboration ou inexistant. Un tel brassage des contenus est dans l'ordre des choses, et permet incidemment d'**éviter que la liste des questions actives ne soit quasi-uniquement constituée que de contenus modifiés répétitivement pour fins d'auto-promotion.**

Il faut de plus noter que **le site autorise la contribution d'une question ou d'une réponse sur le site principal sans même enregistrer un compte** et qu'ainsi sans enregistrement aucune sélection de bonne réponse n'est même possible suivant la déconnexion, confirmant me semble-t-il le peu d'importance de cette sélection. L'important c'est le contenu ; sous licence [CC by-sa](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.fr) et les possibilités qu'elle offre : *partager* et *adapter* (et chaque modification et l'historique est tributaire des attributs de la licence et effectuée conformément à celle-ci).

Qui plus est par un effet d'entraînement une question peut en amener une autre, ce qui **peut contribuer à redresser le [portrait](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/lookup/french.stackexchange.com) du nombre de questions posées** par jour sur le site principal. Ce qui fait qu'on soit réconforté par la possibilité de revoir plusieurs fois ces questions et ces réponses en tête de liste afin que les contributeurs, sortis de leur torpeur ou fraîchement arrivés, puissent un jour enfin en juger et développer d'autres contenus.

Enfin on ne connaît pas la mécanique exacte se cachant derrière le processus auquel tu fais allusion mais d'autres questions (par exemple [celle-ci](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/33737/19187)) que celles de l'utilisateur dont tu parles ont fait l'objet du même traitement. Il se peut que l'utilisateur *Community* réagisse à sa récente appropriation du contenu ou au peu de vote qui y soit rattaché ou qu'il soit déclenché justement par le manque de nouveau contenu sur le site... Le recyclage est dans l'air du temps.

---

Tout ça pour dire que les gens qui ont conçu le site ont pensé à leur affaire et que le fait pour une question de remonter dans la liste des questions actives dans le contexte que tu décris est parfaitement utile et même souhaitable à mon avis.

Comment: "Il est mieux d'attendre d'avoir une bonne réponse plutôt que d'accepter des réponses en quelques minutes sans que la communauté ne se soit penchée sur leur valeur, **ce qui pourrait même décourager certains autres utilisateurs de contribuer**  ... ." This answer (& IMHO, especially the part quoted/emphasized above) should be required reading. I'd hate to think that users who accept quickly/prematurely (& then seemingly change their minds more often than their proverbial *slips*) are doing so merely to get the acceptance points ASAP, but unfortunately I can think of no other legitimate reason.

Comment: @PapaPoule It's possible some people need closure before moving on to something else. Analyzing behavior is quite difficult. It's possible they might assume people will react to the selecting of an answer by contributing further etc. The rep you make by selecting seems like poor incentive for doing it quickly but then again, dopamine-triggering rewards might be more stimulating for some. It may just be some sense of duty or orderly conduct or the need to reward the first person who posts.

Comment: Those are all good points. Thanks.